# PDFium - Reading Values of PDF Text Form Fields?

Tags: c#, vb.net, forms, pdf, pdfium

I am using PDFium to load a PDF on my Windows-Form via Visual Basic .NET. The PDF contains form fields. There is a Windows-Forms-Button that allows me to save the PDF on hard disk.

Is it possible to read the entered values ON the PDF with PDFium once the save button is clicked?

Ideas based on Visual C# .Net are also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is not present in the original Pdfium engine. But the vendor says that this ability will be provided in the next release of Pdfium.Net SDK which is expected soon.

Comment: The new version with form fields support is available now. Look [here](http://pdfium.patagames.com/Help/html/30a08af8-ecae-4ebd-902c-46d183ea4dcd.htm) for details